# Checkbox for multiple values throws exception for wrong type array given

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I tried some things and I am unable to add a multiple checkbox. When I submit the form I get this error message:

> Expected argument of type "string or null", "array" given at property path "caractere_emotion".

My PersonnageType.php

```
->add('caractere_emotion', ChoiceType::class, [
    'required' => false,
    'label' => 'Émotions',
    'choices' => [
        'Actif' => 'Actif',
        'Créatif' => 'Créatif',
        'Génie' => 'Génie',
        'Créatif' => 'Créatif',
        'Joyeux' => 'Joyeux',
        'Morose' => 'Morose',
        'Pitre' => 'Pitre',
        'Romantique' => 'Romantique',
        'Sang Chaud' => 'Sang Chaud',
        'Sûr de lui' => 'Sûr de lui',
    ],
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
])
```

My Personnage.php entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $caractere_emotion;
```

CharacterController.php

```
class CharacterController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $personnage = new Personnage();
      $form = $this->createForm(PersonnageType::class, $personnage);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $em->persist($personnage);
                $em->flush();
            }

        return $this->render('character/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Template :

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_row(form.competences) }}
 {{ form_row(form.principes) }}
 {{ form_row(form.autres_personnalite) }}
 {{ form_row(form.caractere_emotion) }}
 {{ form_row(form.caractere_loisir) }}
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Terminer</button>
 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: can you show the `createForm` call + context ...  and your template?

Comment: after considering your code, I must admit, that I don't see problems, unless your PersonnageType has a problem. I mean ... it says multiple, which *should* allow it to be an array. could you please add the output from `dump($request->request->all());` to your question, add the code before the `$em = ...` line (first line of your function). The output should appear in the profiler bar at the bottom or somewhere on the screen. Something is weird, that much is clear.

Comment: does this only happen, when you *edit* an entity or also when you *create* one? because you might have to fix the old rows, when you changed the Column definition.

Comment: the dump explain that I have the array :p, sorry for my english i'm french. I have created an other entity with juste one field (choicetype mulitple) and it's work. But my main entity doesn't work. At the beginning it was a string, and I change in the Personnage.php Column(type"string") to (type="array") and I use the command doctrine schema force.

Comment: okay, the error message should also show the line, at which it fails in your code (maybe scroll down a bit). Tbh: I'm not fond of the `type="array"` column definition ...

Comment: No i have juste an array and a token not anymore.

Comment: what do you suggest? I tried json_array and is the same

Comment: might be a weird idea, but have you cleared the cache?

Comment: it's same after cache clear

Comment: If you are still in development phase then you might consider wiping your database and recreating it.